# Case class value not found

Tags: scala, class, case, local

Why accessing case class King in "figures match" informs me that the case class is not found? "not found: value King"

```
class Field {
    val size: Int = StdIn.readInt()
    var matrix: List[List[Boolean]] = List.fill(size, size)(true)
    val figures: List[List[Figure]] = List()

    def inRange(figures: List[List[Figure]]) = {
        figures match {
            case King() => field.forEach(matrix) {
               if (matrix == true) {
                  if (Math.abs(m1-m2) <= 1 || Math.abs(n1-n2) <= 1) matrix = false
               }
            }
        }
    }

    abstract class Figure {
        case class Rook()
        case class Knight()
        case class Bishop()
        case class Queen()
        case class King()

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`King` is inside the abstract class `Figure` and is not visible outside it.

I guess, you are trying to do something like below

```
trait Figure

case class Rook() extends Figure
case class Knight() extends Figure
case class Bishop() extends Figure
case class Queen() extends Figure
case class King() extends Figure
```

Now `Rook`, `Knight` ... are Figures and inheritance semantics apply to them. The above code is called as declaring algebraic datatypes.

Now given a figure of type Figure, you can pattern match and find what figure it is exactly.

```
val figure: Figure = Rook()

figure match {
 case Rook() => "found Rook"
 case _ =>  "Not Rook"
}
```

The above code is now valid. Your code becomes

```
abstract class Figure //Figure can be trait as well.

case class Rook() extends Figure
case class Knight() extends Figure
case class Bishop() extends Figure
case class Queen() extends Figure
case class King() extends Figure
```

Based on what you are trying to achieve

```
val listOfFigures: List[List[Figure]] = ....

listOfFigures.flatMap { figures =>
  figures.map { figure =>
   figure match {
     case Rook() => "Rook logic"
     case _ => "Some other logic"
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: It does work, but only when I pattern-match it to a one given Figure. When I pattern-match it to a List[List[Figure]] it says: pattern type is incompatible with expected type; found : Field.this.Rook.type required: List[List[Field.this.Figure]]. How do I traverse INSIDE the list of figures?

Comment: @Megoh sorry for the mistake. You have to get to inner value for pattern matching. Edited the code please check

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `King` is defined inside the abstract class `Figure`. I guess what you're looking for is inheritance. Use `extends` to achieve that:

```scala
abstract class Figure
case class Rook() extends Figure
case class Knight() extends Figure
case class Bishop() extends Figure
case class Queen() extends Figure
case class King() extends Figure
```

Also, I would recommend using `case object`s instead of `case class`es if you don't need any parameters on Rook, Knight, etc.

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

As Pamu explained you want to set the Figures as an algebric data type. You can set them as case objects instead of case classes since you don't have any attributes:

```
trait Figure

case object Rook extends Figure
case object Knight extends Figure
case object Bishop extends Figure
case object Queen extends Figure
case object King extends Figure
```

and then

```
val figures: List[List[Figure]] = List()

def inRange(figures: List[List[Figure]]) = {
  val f = figures.flatMap(identity)
   f.map {
       case King => field.forEach(matrix) {
         if (matrix == true) {
           if (Math.abs(m1 - m2) <= 1 || Math.abs(n1 - n2) <= 1) matrix = false
         }
       }
     }
}
```